# Как избежать перезаписи PendingIntent в Android?

Tags: android, android-notification, pendingintent

Приложение должно создавать уведомления различающиеся по содержанию, однако, при создании нового PendingIntent, все предыдущие перезаписываются и все уведомления приходят с содержанием последнего. У каждого PendingIntent свой уникальный requestCode. Пробовал ставить всевозможные флаги, приложение создает либо последнее уведомление, либо все уведомления с содержанием последнего.

```
private void restartNotify() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeNotification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, Integer.valueOf(CreateActivity.getLastEventId()), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

TimeNotification.class

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("e", CreateActivity.getRep());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(CreateActivity.gettitle());


    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
            Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int NOTIFY_ID = Integer.valueOf(CreateActivity.getLastEventId());
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);}
```

Comment: Вы нашли решение этой проблеме?

Answer (score 0):

Задавайте каждому intent разные action

```
intent.setAction("какое-нибудь значение");
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Вы написали что пробовали разные requestCode, но в коде у вас захардкожен 0 в отправке  нотификации. В этом скорее всего проблема

Comment: Там создается другой intent, задача которого открыть активность, при нажатии на приложение, а у меня перезаписывается intent, который отправляет уведомление

Comment: а, точно. Я не досмотрел. Может здесь ответ найдете http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/204-urok-119-pendingintent-flagi-requestcode-alarmmanager.html

Comment: У вас этот метод CreateActivity.getLastEventId() возвращает точно разные значения?

Comment: Да, были сомнения, но потом проверил

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь не в перезаписи `PendingIntent`, а в статических обращениях к `CreateActivity`.
Вывод уведомлений планируется посредством `AlarmManager`, соответственно `onReceive()` выполняется когда наступит запланированное время вывода и на тот момент методы `CreateActivity` будут возвращать данные для последнего запланированного уведомления, а не для того, чьё время наступило.
Вместо этого нужно передать все необходимые данные в ресивер через его интент, для этого передаём их планирующему методу и записываем в экстра:

```
private void restartNotify(int id, String title, ArrayList<String> data) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeNotification.class);
    intent.putExtra("NOTIFY_ID", id);
    intent.putExtra("TITLE", title);
    intent.putExtra("LIST_DATA", data);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
            .getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

В ресивере достаём из экстра и передаём в уведомление:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int NOTIFY_ID = intent.getIntExtra("NOTIFY_ID", 0);
    ArrayList<String> list = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("LIST_DATA");
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("TITLE");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ListActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("e", list);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title);


    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND |
            Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```